# how to select all the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select all the values of the checkbox with a same id.

```
<select name="marked" id="mark" onchange="checkdata()">
        <option value="">SELECT</option>
        <option value="all">ALL</option>
        <option value="none">NONE</option>
        <option value="read">READ</option>
        <option value="unread">UNREAD</option>
       </select>

 <tr class="read">
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="marked" name="id[]" value="<?php echo message['id'];?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $message['to'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message['from'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message['subject'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message['message']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message['date'];?></td>
        </tr>
```

how can i select all the checkboxes

Comment: A ID should be unique, use a class. Do you wanna use jQuery?

Comment: $('input.marked').attr('checked', 'checked'); // use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript should do it:

```
inputs = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
for (id in inputs) {
   inputs[id].checked = "checked";
}
```